# Make a child of a div's position fixed to the top of the div on scroll and also animate height of child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I have div called `box` with a `header` div as a child. when the div scrolls I want that header div to be sticked(fixed) to the top so the users can always see the header. when the user scrolls down,the header's height should decrease to take up less space but to still allow users to see the header content. When the user scrolls back up the header should be unstuck and the height should be like the way it was before any scrolling took place when it was at the top.

I don't like my attempt I'm about to show you because I get the `offset` of the box relative to the document. I feel like that might not be necessary because there might be a css solution. [this](http://jsfiddle.net/raving/0mLzseby/) one is for the scroll of the whole document. That demo shows using position fixed and it fixes to the top of the page. I cant use position fixed because I believe that is meant for the window and not for divs so what the next best thing?

I dont like how the `header`'s width is over the scrollbars. and the animation is jumpy and it doesn't work.

```js
$(function(){
  var btop = $(".box").offset().top;
  bwidth = $(".box").innerWidth();
  $(".box").on("scroll", function(e){

    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50){
      $(this).find(".header").css({
        "position" : "absolute",
        "top" : btop,
        "max-width" : bwidth,
      }).animate({
        "height" :"2em"
      })
    }else{
      $(this).find(".header").css({
        "position" : "static",
        "top" : btop,
        "max-width" : bwidth
      }).animate({
        "height" :"3em"
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.box{
  margin: 4em auto;
  height: 12em;
  width: 20em;
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
  /*position: relative;*/
}
.header{
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.content{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: powderblue;
  height: 12em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="header">This will stick</div>
  <div class="content">Other content</div>
  <div class="content">Somemore content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will be more simple to set a position absolute to your `header` and `content` and set the scroll on your `content` div.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by set scroll on `content`. why would `content`  be scrolling? oh. you mean to have the `content` move up when the box scrolls?EDIT then ill have to mak the the z index of the content lower than the header

Comment: I post an answer to explain what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an idea, but in your situation, you can fake a sticky header with a simple trick.

1. Remove the `overflow-y: scroll` property of your `.box div`.
2. Set a `position: absolute` property to your `.header`.
3. Add a div `.content-container` who contains your `.content div` and
   set it a `position: absolute` property too and an `overflow-y: scroll`.

This way your header is always on top of your `.box div` and you can scroll your content. Then with your JS code you can change the height of your header on `scroll event`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.content').scroll(function(){
    if ($('.content').scrollTop() >= 60){
      $('.header').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('.header').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.box{
  margin: 4em auto;
  height: 360px;
  width: 20em;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.header{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: height 0.3s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.header.sticky{
  height: 30px;
}
.content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  background: powderblue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content > div{
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="header">This will stick</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Somemore content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks for your idea and that I'm going to keep this question open to see if someone has another solution.